# Realigning x-axis on geom_histogram in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

When creating a `geom_histogram` in `ggplot`, the bin labels appear directly underneath the bars. How can I make it so that they appear on either side of the bin, so that they describe the range of each bin (so that the bin that includes cases from 0 to 10 will appear between the 0 and 10 labels)?

I tried using

```
geom_histogram(position=position_nudge(5))
```

However, the histogram I'm using is stacked (to differentiate categories within each bin), and this effect is ruined when I add this position. Is there another way of doing it? Maybe moving the axis labels themselves instead of the bars?

Reproducible code:

```
dd<-data.frame(nums=c(1:20,15:30,40:55),cats=c(rep("a",20),rep("b",30),rep("c",2)))
ggplot(dd, aes(nums))+geom_histogram(aes(nums,fill=cats),dd,binwidth = 10)
```

results in this:

[image: Looks like this]

I want the bars to be shifted to the right by 5, so that the 0 aligns with the left-hand side of the histogram

Comment: Would be easier for readers if you create a reproducible problem & show the plot that you want (even with Paint).

Comment: @Tung edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to define breaks and labels

```
n <- 10
ggplot(dd, aes(nums, fill=cats)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = n, boundary = 0) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,55,n), labels = seq(0,55, n))
```

[image]

Comment: The only problem there is that the max isn't known in advance. I guess I can get around that easily enough...

Comment: try o replace the `55` with sth. like `max(dd$nums)`

Answer (score 0):

The following moves the labels of the axis. I wasn't sure how to move the ticks on the x axis so I removed them.

```
ggplot(dd, aes(nums))+geom_histogram(aes(nums),dd,binwidth = 10)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 5),
        axis.ticks.x  = element_blank())
```

Comment: I thought 'hjust' is only between 0 and 1

Comment: Just tried it, as expected, the results are erratic, because that's not how `hjust` works.